# How to mention dimensionRation for ConstraintLayout with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

We have `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` for ConstraintLayout while using in with XML. Likewise, how to use dimensionRatio with jetpack compose.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [aspectRatio](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).aspectRatio(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)), you need to import

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.aspectRatio
```

and then use it as follow

```kotlin
Box(modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(0.5f))
```

Comment: Tried the same it doesn't works us expected. Also, aspectRatio won't work like width:height. But, I need to have 1:2 ratio